# SQL GROUP BY (Multiple groups)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

## edit: seems to work in sqlfiddle... must be an error occurring somewhere else. Thanks guys.

---

## http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f867c/1

---

I'm really stuck with counting and grouping in SQL.

The important table is `transaction_items` -- if someone buys 4 of the same bike @ 100 pound each, then there are four rows inserted into `transaction_items`, one row for each quantity (this has been done for a reason, I don't want a `quantity` column.

What I need to do is get all of the records from `transaction_items` where `charge_id = '12345'` and group them by `transaction_items.usersid` AND `transaction_items.item_code` - ultimately giving me a list of groups, each group relating to a unique user and a unique product. So a user can have more than one group if they had multiple products in the cart. if user 1 had purchase 2 x item 1 and 4 x item 2 there would be two groups for user 1, one for item 1 with a count of 2, and one group for item 2, with a count of 4. At the moment, I can only seem to get one group.

So if I have this in transaction_items:

```
|  id  |  charge_id  |  usersid  |  item_code  |
|   1  |      12345  |       12  |         66  |
|   2  |      12345  |       12  |         66  |
|   3  |      66666  |       11  |         66  |
|   4  |      12345  |       12  |         66  |
|   5  |      12345  |        6  |         22  |
|   6  |      77777  |       10  |         66  |
|   7  |      12345  |       12  |         66  |
|   8  |      44444  |       23  |         66  |
|   9  |      12345  |        6  |         22  |
```

and I want to group the data first by `charge_id AND usersid AND item_code` I would want to get this data back:

```
Array
(

    // The array should contain arrays for each pair of usersid's and item_codes, that all have the same charge_id

    [0] => Array
        (
            //This is a unique group for usersid and item_code

            [charge_id] => '12345'
            [usersid] => '12' 
            [item_code] => '66'
            [num_of_records] => '4'          
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            //This is a unique group for usersid and item_code

            [charge_id] => '12345'
            [usersid] => '6'
            [item_code] => '22'
            [num_of_records] => '2'          
        )
)
```

So I'm looking to get an array that:

1. Groups all records with identical charge_id's, usersid's and item_code's
2. Get the data back in a useable format, with a count (just like a quantity)
3. The count (quantity) should only be made for each group, not all records

What I'm getting now seems to be just one product ID, just one usersid, but a total count of records reflecting all users, and items, the exact opposite of what I'm aiming for! (The dummy output below reflects use of the example table above):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [charge_id] => '12345'
            [usersid] => '12'
            [item_code] => '66'
            [num_of_records] => '6'          
        )
)
```

## My query at the moment:

```
$items = $db->query("
                SELECT 
                    count(transaction_items.id) as num_of_records,
                    transaction_items.*
                FROM 
                    transaction_items 
                WHERE
                    transaction_items.charge_id = :charge
                AND
                    transaction_items.lmsid = :lmsid
                GROUP
                BY
                    transaction_items.usersid,
                    transaction_items.charge_id,
                    transaction_items");
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

---

## Edit & Update

This is all down to the WHERE clause. When I delete it the query works perfectly but collects ALL records from the items table, whereas I just want the ones where the `charge_id = '12345'`. Therefore I think the topic of this question strictly relates to the combined use of GROUP BY and WHERE and why I'm not getting the results I'm expecting.

To simplify matters, the query is now:

```
$items = $db->query("SELECT 
                        count(transaction_items.id) as num_of_records,
                        item_code, 
                        usersid
                    FROM 
                        transaction_items
                    WHERE
                        charge_id = '12345'
                    GROUP
                    BY
                        usersid,
                        charge_id,
                        item_code
                        ");
```

Comment: `transaction_items.*` is a bad idea.  List out your field names.

Comment: You're right, the WHERE clause is restricting it to bringing back one record, but without the `WHERE charge_id = :charge` I will be getting every record from the transaction_items table - how can I filter it to a specific `charge_id` value? I've now listed out the `transaction_items.*` individually, I don't know why I didn't in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow - is this what you mean?

```
CREATE TABLE  transaction_items
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,charge_id  INT NOT NULL
,usersid  INT NOT NULL
,item_code INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO transaction_items VALUES
(1  ,12345  ,12  ,66),
(2  ,12345  ,12  ,66),
(3  ,66666  ,11  ,66),
(4  ,12345  ,12  ,66),
(5 ,12345 , 6 ,22),
(6 ,77777 ,10 ,66),
(7 ,12345 ,12 ,66),
(8 ,44444 ,23 ,66),
(9 ,12345 , 6 ,22);

SELECT charge_id
     , usersid
     , item_code
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM transaction_items 
 GROUP 
    BY charge_id
     , usersid
     , item_code;
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+
| charge_id | usersid | item_code | COUNT(*) |
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     12345 |       6 |        22 |        2 |
|     12345 |      12 |        66 |        4 |
|     44444 |      23 |        66 |        1 |
|     66666 |      11 |        66 |        1 |
|     77777 |      10 |        66 |        1 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

EDIT: I'm still confused...

```
SELECT charge_id
     , usersid
     , item_code
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM transaction_items
 WHERE charge_id = 12345
 GROUP
    BY charge_id
     , usersid
     , item_code;
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+
| charge_id | usersid | item_code | COUNT(*) |
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     12345 |       6 |        22 |        2 |
|     12345 |      12 |        66 |        4 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

!?!?!

Comment: You're on the right track, but what you've posted there is what I already have. Look at your table above, what would you add to your query to just get the rows where `charge_id = '12345'`, because a WHERE clause is only getting one row, with a total count from all of the rows its combined. And without the WHERE clause, I'm getting all rows.

Comment: From your edit, my output would be `charge_id = 12345`, `usersid = 6`, `COUNT(*) = 6`. It seems to only retreive the first row of data and a count of all rows.

Comment: `charge_id = 12345` is from the where clause. `usersid = 6` I have no idea why it's targeting one record, perhaps it's picking the first? and 'COUNT(*)= 6' is because the single record is returning with a total count of all records with the WHERE clause charge_id -> even the ones it's not brining back (I.E. 2 + 4 from your table above comes back at 6, with the one record).

Comment: But that seems to be what you want !?!?!

Comment: Not at all, I'm after exactly what you've posted in your edit, the two separate rows, a return of a record for every unique usersid/item_code pair match. At the moment I'm just getting back one row with a single COUNT value of all rows. Let me build a SQLFIDDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated query looks fine to me, although I'm not sure the columns `amount_paid` and `valid_days` they aren't part of the `GROUP BY` or listed in any of your example.. are these other aggregate functions?

Are you sure your data is as you expect it to be.. run a

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_items WHERE charge_id = :charge_id
```

to be sure you have more than one separate group. Are you sure you aren't leaving out some data?

Also you are `GROUP`ing `BY` `courseid` instead of `item_code`, is that correct?

**Following your update:**

That makes more sense, but your example query should work now.

I'm expecting that you have some `JOIN`s, possibly a `LEFT JOIN` that is returning `null` where you expect an id and as a result all the `null`s get grouped together.

Try and break down your query bit by bit and make sure all the separate sections are working as intended.

Comment: Yes, I should stress that my examples have been greatly simplified to 'deconfuse' the question, though I think it may have now caused the opposite. Let me make some edits to clear up the clouds.

Comment: Thanks for the update and help here. Unfortunately I've already stripped the query right down, what you can see is what I'm currently testing with. I'm building a SQLFIDDLE now

Comment: @Arbiter, that query is fine, your data must be rum.

Comment: Yeah SQL FIDDLE confirms that -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f867c/1 -- This is driving me mad. I have to sleep now so I'll be back on this when I'm up in 6 hours. Cheers for looking into this guys and girls!

Comment: Now, if only a fiddle had been provided (or requested) in the first place ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry Touché! :)

Comment: True that (+1), lesson learned - which is what programming is all about, right? :/